# Some input files use or override a deprecated API in android studio 3.0

Tags: android

i have update my gradle version 4.4 and then build my apk it show me error

```
Error:Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**After this error i have add -`Xlint:unchecked` in Default Setting >> Java compiler >>additional command line parameters (text box)**

But it not solve so please help me to resolve it.

MY **app.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ejobbox.ejobbox"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

repositories {
    // You can also use jcenter if you prefer
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //Add New Dependency and compile
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'cc.cloudist.acplibrary:library:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    //Searchable Dependency
    implementation 'com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:1.9'
    // google Services Depedency

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also i found same version specification warning in implementation `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'` and  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'` then i have try and change it version and check with all new version but warning as it is so i have fixed it with `//noinspection GradleCompatible`.

Please check and let me know how can i resolve this error.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code in defaultConfig{} after

Code:  flavorDimensions "app"

Reference Link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-2-enter-flavor-dimensions-4ad7f486f6

After add this code let me know any error.

Comment: it show me error : 

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processClient1DevDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.ejobbox.ejobbox.client1'

Comment: google-services.json file is missing in your project or package name different in google-service.json file.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: i check everything is ok not file missing or no package name changed.

Comment: I have found the issue in your code.  Please send me your whole app gradle file.  Because as per your package name is com.ejobbox.ejobbox but the error is throw package name is com.ejobbox.ejobbox.client1 .